# User is created however cannot login after logging out MeteorJS

Tags: meteor

So I'm creating a new user as my template is created. The user is being created successfully, and automatically is logged in however if I sign out and then try to sign in , I get the 'user not found'. Here is my code

```
Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  // counter starts at 0
  this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
  var userObject = {
    username: "anotherTest",
    mail: "anotherTest@me.com",
    password: "testingME"
  };

  Accounts.createUser(userObject, function(error){
     console.log('User created');
     console.log(error);
  });
});
```

And here is the full project in case it is needed.
https://github.com/hayk94/UbMvp/tree/accountsTEST

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use client side accounts management to perform a task it hasn't been designed for.

Client side accounts package purpose is to specifically allow new users to create their account and expect to be logged in immediately.

You have to remember that certain functions can be run on the client and/or on the server with different behaviors, Accounts.createUser docs specify that : "On the client, this function logs in as the newly created user on successful completion."

On the contrary, "On the server, it returns the newly created user id." (it doesn't mess with the currently logged in user on the client).

In order to solve your problem, you should write a server side method creating a new user and be able to call it from your client side admin panel, after filling correctly a user creation form of your own design.